# Improper Riemann integral and imaginary exponential of real polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

Let $P(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$ be a real polynomial of degree $\geq 2$. 
What are the conditions on $P$ so that 
$$
I_P:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{iP(x)} dx 
$$ 
exists as an improper Riemann integral ?
Already for $n=1$, I dont know the answer, even though my guess is that in this case, it exists for all $P$ of degree $\geq 2$. Is that true and why ?

A related question: at least for $n=1$, do we have a closed formula for  $I_P$ when $P$ is a monomial? For example, Mathematica gives $I_{x^3}=-(2\pi)/\Gamma(-1/3)$ and other complicated expressions involving the $\Gamma$ function for higher degrees. What is behind these formulas?